# Distributing UI across various scripts in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I’m working on a desktop application and it’s UI is currently coded in multiple scripts each sharing an instance of the root class (Tk) from the main script. But in order to do so, each script imports tkinter as “from tkinter import *” and I’m wondering if this is good practice - especially when I plan on freezing and distributing this app later on?

Comment: Good practice is to `import tkinter` or use an alias, `import tkinter as tk`. This way does not contaminate the global namespace and lets you differentiate between names imported from different modules. This allows you to always see where a widget comes from and makes your code easier to read for other developers.

Comment: The best practice is described by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and it discourages wildcard imports (`from x import *`)